# In Judges 15:19 - Was the לְחִ֣י Lechi = "Jawbone" used only as a geographic origin story of Lehi's Spring (עֵ֚ין הַקּוֹרֵא֙)?

Tags: judges

In Judges 15:14-19, Samson (Shimshon, שִׁמְשׁ֔וֹן) defeats the Philistines with an odd weapon : a donkey’s jawbone (Lechi, לְחִ֣י) - calling the place of his victory “Level-Jawbone” (רָ֥מַת לֶֽחִי).

- While Samson was thirsty after the Philistine battle at Lehi, he prayed to find something to drink and God cleaved the socket of Samson’s weapon to make water pour out of the donkey’s jawbone. After reviving his spirit by drinking water from the donkey’s jawbone, Samson called his place of rejuvenation “Eye of the Crier” ( עֵ֚ין הַקּוֹרֵא֙). - Referencing an actual Spring of water at Lehi which Judges 15:19.

**Judges / Shoftim 15:19 [MT]**

> “ And God cleaved the socket which was in the jawbone, and water came out of it, and he drank, and his spirit returned and he revived; therefore he called its name En-hakkore, which is in Lehi until this day. “ ( וַיִּבְקַ֨ע אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶת־הַמַּכְתֵּ֣שׁ אֲשֶׁר־בַּלֶּ֗חִי וַיֵּצְא֨וּ מִמֶּ֚נּוּ מַ֙יִם֙ וַיֵּ֔שְׁתְּ וַתָּ֥שָׁב רוּח֖וֹ וַיֶּ֑חִי עַל־כֵּ֣ן | קָרָ֣א שְׁמָ֗הּ עֵ֚ין הַקּוֹרֵא֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר בַּלֶּ֔חִי עַ֖ד הַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּֽה )

**Was the לְחִ֣י Lechi = "Jawbone" weapon simply used as a literary device for the geographic origin story of Lehi's Spring (עֵ֚ין הַקּוֹרֵא֙)?**

Answer (score 1):

A riddle is a question that the listener must answer. "What has two eyes but can't see?" etc.

Whereas the passage here is one of many accounts in the Bible of how things came to be called - it gives an answer, rather than asking a question, so I don't see how it could possibly be classified as a riddle.